# elasticsearch how to reset an field for all docs at once?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have and index with 1mln documents and need to set value `NULL` for field `status` to ALL documents in this index. Is it possible? Or the only way is to reindex all documents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only way to do this is to reindex all the documents.

You can update your mapping so that status.null_value = "NULL", so that documents indexed after that will have that value.

Comment: maybe i can use an ES `script`? It must be faster than re-upload entire index via API, right? If so, can you give an example?

Comment: You can try this plugin. I've never used it: scrolling and bulk indexing work fine for me.

https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex

Comment: Yeah scroll and bulk index. Updating won't be of much use. When you update a document in ES, it is basically re-indexed. So you won't get much benefit other than saving network IO.